# Is llama lama or glama?

Tags: etymology, biology, scientific-names

I went to a zoo today, and I noticed that the scientific name of [llama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llama) is *Lama glama*.
It seems to me that both *lama* and *glama* are latinized versions of "llama".
Why were two different versions of the word chosen for genus and species?
I could imagine that they were latinized from different source languages, but I still find the inconsistency striking.

It seems that Linné originally grouped llamas under camels and named the species *Camelus glama*.
I understand preserving the species name but I find it rather weird that a different spelling was introduced for the genus.

Why is there a 'g' in the first place?
Is 'gl' supposed to be pronounced like the Italian 'gli' or something similar?
I do not know of a language where one would actually have a /g/ in llama's name.

(I apologize that I could not resist choosing that title.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To complement @brianpck answer:

First, let's state right away the obvious: since all known species of llamas are endemic to South America, it is highly unlikely that there is a classical latin word to name them.

[Wheeler (2005)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1095-8312.1995.tb01037.x) offered a short review of the taxonomical history of llamas:

> In  1758,  Linnaeus  described  the  two  domestic  New  World  camelids  as *Camelus  glama* “Camelus  peruvianus  Glama  dictus”  (llama)  and *Camelus pacos* “Camelus  peruvianus  laniger  Pacos  dictus”  (alpaca), placing  them  together  in a single  genus  with  the  Old  World  dromedary  and  bactrian  camels, *Camelus dromedarius* and *Camelus bactrianus*. The  two  remaining  New  World  species,  the wild  guanaco  and  vicuña,  were  subsequently  designated *Camelus guanicoe* by Müller  in  1776  and *Camelus vicugna* by  Molina  in  1782.  As  early as 1775, Frisch  proposed  that  the  four  New  World  species  be  placed  in  the  genus *Lama*, but  this  work  is  not  accepted  by  the  International  Commission  on  Zoological Nomenclature  (Hemming,  1985a) and authorship of *Lama* is  credited to Cuvier, 1800  (Hemming,  1985b).

But the nomenclatural history of llamas is even more complex than this as the [*Mammal Species of the World* database page](http://vertebrates.si.edu/msw/mswCFApp/msw/taxon_browser.cfm?msw_id=12515) on the genus *Lama* Cuvier 1800 lists no less than 12 synonyms:

*Aucheria* F. Cuvier, 1830
*Auchenia* Illiger, 1811
*Auchenias* Wagner, 1843
*Dromedarius* Wagler, 1830
*Guanaco* Perry, 1811
*Lacma* Tiedemann, 1804
*Lama* Frisch, 1775
*Llacma* Illiger, 1815
*Llama* Gray, 1852
*Neoauchenia* Ameghino, 1891
*Pacos* Gray, 1872
*Vicunia* Rafinesque, 1815

To go back to the main point: it is not clear why Linnaeus used *glama* instead of *lama* or *llama* because, at the time, it was not compulsory (nor even habitual) to explain the etymology of a species name. Maybe Linnaeus just misheard the Quechua word, we'll never really know. However the reason why the genus name was changed to *Lama* could be because:

- Frisch and Cuvier wanted to correct Linnaeus mistake (if it is indeed a mistake)
- They wanted to avoid a tautonymous name: while Linnaeus seems to have been fond of them (being the author of *Alces alces*, *Bison bison*, *Cricetus cricetus*, *Dama dama* and many many others), the rest of the taxonomical community isn't. In fact the international code of nomenclature had to add an [article specifically allowing them](http://www.nhm.ac.uk/hosted-sites/iczn/code/index.jsp?nfv=&article=23#3.7), to prevent the community from considering them invalids by default.
- Another explanation, maybe less elegant, is that the community erroneously consider Cuvier to have named the genus *Lama*: indeed the [modern sources](http://vertebrates.si.edu/msw/mswCFApp/msw/taxon_browser.cfm?msw_id=12515) linking the name to Cuvier's work are pointing at table 1 from book 1 of *Leçons d'anatomie comparée* as the source from the name. But that table is actually written in french (and needless to say, *Lama* is french for *llama*), and indeed I do not seem to find any occurrence in [*Leçons d'anatomie comparée*](http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/bibliography/6850#/summary) of the word *Lama* where it is employed in any way other than as a vernacular name in french. If it is true, at this point, it doesn't really matter anymore as the name has been employed for more than a century to designate that genus so usage prevails (particularly since Cuvier's work and the usage of the genus name *Lama* predates the first international code of zoological nomenclature).

If in the end the question was: what word to employ in a vernacular context (i. e. non-taxonomical) to designates llamas in latin? I would say that both *glama* and *lama* could be considered, though it might be worth noting that the latin version of wikipedia uses *lama*:

> Lama glama (Linnaeus anno 1758), **vulgo lama**, est mammal familiae Camelidarum. Lama est indigena Americae Meridionalis et Andium montium, accurate Peruviae et Aequatoriae.
>   <sub>Source: https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lama_glama. Emphasis mine.</sub>

Otherwise *auchenia* also makes sense to some extent (it derives from the greek *auchēn* meaning *neck*, and, as far as I know, it has no other meaning than *llama*).

Comment: Interesting. I am not familiar with the *Mammal Species of the World* database, but almost all the "synonyms" strike me as tenuous: a *dromedarius* is very clearly a camel and a *vicunia* (Spanish: vicuña) is related, but distinct, from a llama.

Comment: There are synonyms of the genus *Lama*, not of the species *Lama glama*. *Dromedarius* and *Vicunia* were used as genus name for a group of species having (I assume, because it's usually the reason why genera are considered synonyms) the same type-species as *Lama* or the same set of species as *Lama* making them synonyms of *Lama*.

Answer (score 6):

As you mentioned in your question, Linné originally grouped the llama under the genus "Camelus", as you can see in [Systema Naturae](https://books.google.com/books?id=oXsZAAAAYAAJ&q=lama#v=onepage&q=glama&f=false):

> **Camelus**
>   ...
>   *Camelus* dorso laevi, pectore gibboso
>        Camelus peruvianus **Glama** dictus

It appears that this was later revised to be the genus *Lama* and the species *Glama* in 1758. (Source: [Wikispecies](https://species.wikimedia.org/wiki/Lama_glama)), leading to the current designation as **Lama Glama**

The word *llama* appears to come from the same Quechua word which is more or less pronounced as in Spanish: [ˈʝama]

I have tried to search for usages of either term, but could not locate any. My presumption is that both words were an attempt to Latinize the correct pronunciation of *llama*.

Answer (score 1):

This is speculation, but I believe the name "Glama" is a native name for the animal. Because Spanish became the predominating language of the region, the spelling probably shifted over time to coincide with the common Spanish spelling of the verb "llamar". I have gleaned this from Wikipedia, which sources this from the Oxford English Dictionary. And the oxford english dictionary states that the name of the animal probably originates from the Quechua native civilizations of Peru.

So I should clarify that it is my opinion that the spelling has shifted over time. The facts, according to Oxford dictionary, is that the word originates from Peruvian Quechua languages. It is unclear as of yet, how exactly the spelling changed over time, or why.